# ScalaTest asserting multiple futures using AsyncFunSuiteLike

Tags: scala, scalatest

I've been trying to perform a test that uses a mock Http server to respond and a function that returns a Future[String] or an Exception if the Http server response isn't 200.

I'm trying to achieve a test without using Awaits, but instead AsyncFunSuiteLike.

However the following test seems impossible to resolve without doing it synchronously:

```
test("Error responses") {
    Future.sequence {
      NanoHTTPD.Response.Status.values().toList.filter(status => status.getRequestStatus >= 400).map {
        status => {

          httpService.setStatusCode(status)
          val responseBody = s"Request failed with status $status"
          httpService.setResponseContent(responseBody)
          val errorMessage = s"Error response (${status.getRequestStatus}) from http service: $responseBody"

          recoverToExceptionIf[ServiceException] {
            myObject.httpCall("123456")
          }.map {
            ex => assert(ex.getMessage === errorMessage)
          }
        }
      }
    }.map(assertions => assert(assertions.forall(_ == Succeeded)))
}
```

Basically the problem is that when the Futures are tested, the NanoHTTPD is set to the last valued set in the map, so all `ex.getMessage` are the same. If I run those status codes one by one I do get the desired results, but, is there a way to perform all this in one single Async test?

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, NanoHTTPD is stateful, so you have a race between the `.set...` calls and the `.httpCall`.

If you can spin up a new `httpService` within each Future, then you should be able to parallelize the tests (unless the state in question would be shared across instances, in which case you're likely out of luck).

So you'd have something like (replace `Status` with the type of `status` in your code and `HTTPService` with the type of `httpService`):

```
// following code composed on the fly and not run through the compiler...
def spinUpHTTPService(status: Status, body: String): Future[HTTPService] = {
  // insert the code outside of the test which creates httpService

  httpService.setStatusCode(status)
  httpService.setResponseContent(body)

  httpService
}

test("Error responses") {
  Future.sequence(
    NanoHTTPD.Response.Status.values().toList.filter(status => status.getRequestStatus >= 400).map { status =>
      spinUpHTTPService(status, s"Request failed with status $status")
        .flatMap { httpService =>
          val errorMessage = s"Error response (${status.getRequestStatus}) from http service: $responseBody"

          recoverToExceptionIf[ServiceException] {
            myObject.httpCall("123456")
          } map {
            ex => assert(ex.getMessage === errorMessage)
          }
        } // Future.flatMap
    }  // List.map
  ).map { assertions => assertions.forAll(_ == Succeeded) }
}
```